Derivative of Ridge regression w.r.t. to its input X
Given the Ridge Regression original formulation:
$Y^* = X \theta$
$\theta = \left ( \lambda I+ X^TX\right )^{-1} X^T Y$
where $X$ and $Y$ are the input and target output matrices, respectively.
What is the derivative of $Y^*$ w.r.t. $X$?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

$$Y^* = X \left( \lambda I + X^T X \right)^{-1} X^T Y$$
$$A = \left( \lambda I + X^T X \right)^{-1}$$
$$Y^* = X A X^T Y$$
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial X} = -A (2X) A = -2AXA$$
$$\frac{\partial Y^*}{\partial X} = A X^T Y - 2XAXA X^T Y$$
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial Y^*}{\partial X} = \left( \lambda I + X^T X \right)^{-1} X^T Y - 2X \left( \lambda I + X^T X \right)^{-1} X \left( \lambda I + X^T X \right)^{-1} X^T Y}$$

$
\def\t{\theta}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\BLR#1{\b{\LR{#1}}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\M{M^{-1}}
\def\Y{Y^{*}}
\def\Xt{X^T}
\def\S#1#2{#1_{#2}}
\def\SBR#1#2{\BR{#1}_{#2}}
\def\E#1#2{e_{#1}e_{#2}^T}
$Define the matrix variables $\lbrace M,\t\rbrace$ as
$$\eqalign{
M &= \lambda I + \Xt X &\qiq dM &= \b{\Xt dX + d\Xt X} \\
\t &= \c{\M\Xt Y} &\qiq d\t &= \M\,d\Xt\,Y \g{+d\M}\Xt Y \\
&&&= \M\,d\Xt\,Y \g{-\LR{\M dM\,\M}}\Xt Y \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of the regression model
$$\eqalign{
\Y &= X\t \\
d\Y
 &= dX\:\t \;+\; X\:d\t \\
 &= dX\:\t \;+\; X\M\,d\Xt\,Y - X\M\b{dM}\,\CLR{\M\Xt Y} \\
 &= dX\:\t \;+\; X\M\,d\Xt\,Y - X\M\BLR{\Xt dX + d\Xt X}\c{\t} \\
 &= \LR{I-X\M\Xt}\g{dX}\,\t \;+\; X\M\,\g{d\Xt}\LR{Y-\Y} \\
}$$
Recall that the component-wise self-gradients of a matrix are given by
$$\eqalign{
\grad{X}{\S X{kl}} = \E kl \qif \grad{X^T}{\S X{kl}} = \E lk \\
}$$
where $e_k$ is the standard basis vector, i.e. the $k^{th}$ component is $\tt1$ but all other components are $0$.
So the gradient of $\Y$ wrt the scalar $\S X{kl}$ component
is the following matrix
$$\eqalign{
\grad\Y{\S X{kl}}
 &= \LR{I-X\M\Xt}\g{\E kl}\,\t \;+\; X\M\,\g{\E lk}\LR{Y-\Y} \\
}$$
Extracting the $(i,j)$ component of this matrix
yields the components of the full fourth-order tensor representing
the matrix-by-matrix gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\S\Y{ij}}{\S X{kl}} 
&= \SBR{I-X\M\Xt}{ik}\,\S\t{lj} \;+\; \SBR{X\M}{il}\SBR{Y-\Y}{kj} \\
}$$
When $\lbrace\t,Y,\Y\rbrace$ are vectors rather than matrices, simply omitting the $j$-index will recover the components of the third-order (vector-by-matrix) gradient tensor.
